# How to get the zoom level on maps.google.com using JavaScript?

Tags: google-maps, zooming

I'm using bookmarklets to compare maps from different providers. I would like to get the zoom level from the current map showing on the maps.google.com site.

This is the only working solution I've come up with:

```
    var zoom=gApplication.getPageUrl().split('z=');var z=(zoom[1].length>2 ? zoom[1].substring(0,zoom[1].indexOf('&')) : zoom[1]);
```

It's working OK for now, but I'm not feeling comfortable with it...

I have tried `map.getZoom()` , but map isn't correct for the maps.google.com -site. It works on some other sites where the map-variable has been named map.

Answer (score 0):

you can use map.getZoom();

for more refrence read at http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/ref_getzoom.asp

hope it helps you out..